# How to create a Loading screen in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've written a C# script from a tutorial which works fine when i press space. But i want to do it in case of button for 2D mobile games. The code is given below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LoadingScreen : MonoBehaviour {

public string levelToLoad;

public GameObject background;
public GameObject text;
public GameObject progressBar;

private int loadProgress = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    background.SetActive (false);
    text.SetActive (false);
    progressBar.SetActive (false);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")) {
        StartCoroutine(DisplayLoadingScreen(levelToLoad));
    }
}

IEnumerator DisplayLoadingScreen(string level){
    background.SetActive (true);
    text.SetActive (true);
    progressBar.SetActive (true);

    progressBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3(loadProgress,progressBar.transform.localScale.y, progressBar.transform.localScale.z);

    text.GetComponent<GUIText>().text = "Loading Progress " + loadProgress + "%";

    AsyncOperation async = Application.LoadLevelAsync (level);
    while (!async.isDone) {
        loadProgress = (int)(async.progress * 100);
        text.GetComponent<GUIText>().text = "Loading Progress " + loadProgress + "%";
        progressBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3(async.progress,progressBar.transform.localScale.y, progressBar.transform.localScale.z);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

}

I have some tips how to do that. Somebody suggest me to do the following code in case of button:

```
if (GUI.Button (new Rect(),Button) {
        StartCoroutine(DisplayLoadingScreen(levelToLoad));
    }
```

Actually i don't know how to do that in case of button. Please anybody help me to do the exact code in case of button. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "Button", do you mean Unity's Canvas Button, or GUI Button?

Comment: I mean Canvas button actually. @VenkatatAxiomStudios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, make a method:

```
public void onButtonClick() {
  StartCoroutine(DisplayLoadingScreen(levelToLoad));
}
```

Then in the inspector for the button, associate the "On Click()" handler with your method:

[image: Button Inspector]